# restore server or snapshot tool for students practices

Tags: restore, snapshot

greetings, I am facing a scenario of educational practices, I want to put a server with ubuntu server 22.04 with a basic configuration, after groups of students start to install programs and make their own configurations, once a group finishes, I want to be able to return to the state of the basic configuration; lose everything that the first group of students did, leave the server as before so that another group of students can do their practice installing programs and so on. What program can I use that will allow me to perform this task? What program can I use to return to a state of ubuntu server configuration?

Comment: I would spin up a fresh VM or container for each group.

Comment: You could use Timeshift or Clonezilla with varying degrees of difficulty depending on your familiarity with the tools and exactly how your systems are set up.